# Fastify Swagger & TypeScript: How to put schema for a route returning a ReadableStream of objects

Tags: typescript, fastify, fastify-swagger

A Fastify endpoint (using TS) returns a ReadableStream of objects. Apparently there is no way to tell in response schema that this endpoint returns a stream of objects. How do we create the route to mention stream as return type.

The response is a stream of objects like this

```
{"key":"A","value":"1234"}
{"key":"A","value":"1234"}
...
```

and here is the route:

```
fastify.get('/get-key-value-data', {
  schema: {
    response: {
      '200': KeyValuePair
    }
  }
})
```

how do I replace that `KeyValuePair` to say its a stream of these objects?